# "Вы" или "вы" — как правильно в ответе на вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение

До ноября прошлого года я в своих ответах обычно использовала местоимение **Вы**.

Потом в одном из моих ответов **Вы** "подкорректировали" на **вы**  с формулировкой "Это не переписка, и, стало быть, личное обращение неуместно" (больше ничего не правилось).
[**Человек, который готовит проект**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/435363/revisions)

Два месяца, памятуя о правке, я исправно писала **вы**. Сегодня произошла "контркорректировка": **вы** поменялось на **Вы** (формулировка — опечатка).
[**Киот (?) расположен на стене дома или в стене?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/437073/revisions)

Давайте решим — раз и навсегда! — как все-таки верно?
Получается, что ответы на подобные вопросы мы пишем-и-пишем, а между собой никак к согласию прийти не можем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы вольны использовать оба написания! Приведенные правки, на мой взгляд, бессмысленны, и вы, как автор, можете их откатить.

Comment: Да, конечно, в о л ь н а. Просто не хочется тратить время и эмоции на ненужности. Лично я привыкла обращаться на "Вы" (Ваш вопрос, Ваше предложение, Ваша правка...), мне **так** удобнее. Но если форум решит по-другому, я постараюсь перепривыкнуть.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я бы не стал ждать решения форума, а делал так, как считаю нужным ) Поверьте, это будет правильнее всего. Иногда прислушаться к мнению других хорошо, а иногда это совершенно не обязательно.

Comment: Я тоже против стандартизации в этом вопросе. Пусть каждый проявляет свою индивидуальность, коль правила позволяют.

Comment: @Aer Никак не могу отправить вопрос на "Мете". Программа пишет и пишет: _Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта. Убедитесь, что в нем полностью описана проблема, а также ваши решения в грамматически правильной форме._ Подскажите: что делать? Посмотрите черновик, пожалуйста, если такая возможность есть. Перепробовала несколько вариантов.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова да, знакомая ситуация. Допишите в конце кучу любых символов, опубликуйте вопрос, а затем просто их уберите.

Comment: Благодарю. Попробую.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова если что, пишите!